# Formación de "novohispano" y "neogranadino"

Tags: vocabulario, historia, hispanoamérica, latín, prefijos

Entre los virreinatos españoles estaban Nueva España, con su gentilicio *novohispano*, y Nueva Granada, el suyo *neogranadino*. Pasaron dos siglos entre los dos establecimientos (en 1535 y 1717) pero ¿eso explica por qué estas palabras usaron prefijos distintos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, es un resultado de la moda. En el pasado (y menos frecuentemente, hoy en día) se formaban gentilicios derivados de los topónimos o etnónimos antiguos (ej. de Inglaterra: *anglo-*, de España: *hispano-*, de Portugal: *luso-*, de Japón: *nipo-*, de China: *sino-*, etc.).

Así, ***novohispano*** es un latinismo (de [*Novo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/novus#Latin) + [*Hispānia*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hispania#Latin) < *Nueva España*), como otras palabras de su época<sup>1</sup>.

Actualmente [el prefijo preferido](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Formaci%C3%B3n_de_gentilicios_extranjeros#Seg.C3.BAn_a.C3.B1adidos_diversos) para expresar algo 'nuevo' es [*neo-*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QO8dyjW) (del griego *νεο-*), así que hay muchas palabras de los últimos dos siglos formadas así, como *neocolonialismo, neolatino, neonato* etc, incluyendo la mayoría de<sup>2</sup> los gentilicios de países/regiones/ciudades llamadas *Nueva ...*, como ***neogranadino*** (*Nueva Granada*).

Sin embargo, estas reglas no son absolutas; hay [una minoría](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=novohispano%2Cneohispano&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3) de gente que usa la forma modernizada *neohispano*, pero por popularidad la forma antigua es mucho más común. Por otro lado [una minoría](http://dle.rae.es) de gente usa la forma *novogranadino* (en lugar de *neogranadino*) por la influencia de *novohispano*. También hay regiones cuyo prefijo 'Nuevo' ha sido lexicalizado por completo, como en [nuevoburgués](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Suiza) (Nuevoburgo).

Entre estas tres formas de denominar tales gentilicios, hay casos en los que dos formas son más o menos igual de populares e.g. [*neoleonés* vs *nuevoleonés*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nuevoleon%C3%A9s%2Cneoleon%C3%A9s&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3).

Y casos en los que las tres formas se emplean e.g. [*novomexicano/novomejicano*, *neomexicano/neomejicano* y *nuevomexicano*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=novomexicano%2Cneomexicano%2Cnuevomexicano&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3).

> ENTRE las voces neohispano y novohispano ¿cuál debe usarse? Pues la que uno guste. Es muy antigua la primera; la segunda se ha impuesto desde hace más de medio siglo. Yo prefiero aquella, pues por influjo de *novohispano* podría caer en la tentación de escribir *novófito* en vez de neófito, *novoclásico* a cambio de neoclásico, *novologismo* en lugar de neologismo, y *novoliberal* por neoliberal. Sí, prefiero neohispano a novohispano, y neoleonés a novoleonés, aunque no por ello llamaría Salvador Neo a Salvador Novo.
>
> - [*Perlas*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=huZsN0oQOkUC&pg=PA28&dq=%22neohispano%22), Nikito Nipongo (p.28)

---

<sup>1. e.g. *ultoniano*, del topónimo tradicional de Úlster en latín, *Ultonia*</sup>

<sup>2. e.g. [neoyorquino](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QPPiUEc) (Nueva York), [neojerseyés o neojerseíta](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Estados_Unidos) (Nueva Jérsey), [neohampshireño o neohantoniense](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Estados_Unidos) (Nuevo Hampshire), [neozelandés](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QPQ6yJD) (Nueva Zelanda), [neosurgalés](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Australia) (Nueva Gales del Sur), [neoescocés](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Canad%C3%A1) (Nueva Escocia), [neobrunswiqués](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Canad%C3%A1) (Nuevo Brunswick), [neoespartano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QOO7W0e) (Nueva Esparta), [neocaledonio](http://publications.europa.eu/code/es/es-5000500.htm) (Nueva Caledonia), [neorruso](https://web.archive.org/web/20160810062028/http://semanariovoz.com/2014/10/27/fraude-en-ucrania-nueva-rusia-espera-nuevo-ataque) (Nueva Rusia), [neodelhiense](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_India)​
o [neodelhí](http://www.infodefensa.com/mundo/2016/05/13/noticia-fuerza-naval-india.html) (Nueva Delhi), [neogerundense](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Cuba) (Nueva Gerona), [neobaztanés](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Espa%C3%B1a/Madrid) (Nuevo Baztán), [neojarillense](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Espa%C3%B1a/Andaluc%C3%ADa/C%C3%A1diz) (Nueva Jarilla)</sup>

<sup>**Sino** [granadero](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Colombia/Magdalena) (Nueva Granada), [castellano](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Colombia/Meta) (Castilla la Nueva), [germanino](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Paraguay) (Nueva Germania), [palmirense](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Uruguay) (Nueva Palmira), [villanovense](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Guatemala) (Villa Nueva), [daianovés](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Top%C3%B3nimos_de_Espa%C3%B1a/Comunidad_Valenciana/Alicante) (Daya Nueva), [neosoliense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bansk%C3%A1_Bystrica#Etymology) (Banská Bystrica ant. `lat.` *Neosolium* < `germ.` *Neusohl*)</sup>

Comment: @AaronBrick aunque [si alargas hasta 2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=novomexicano%2Cneomexicano%2Cnuevomexicano&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3) (lo último que sale en Ngram) se ve cómo _nuevomexicano_ decae (manteniendo la primera posición) y _neomexicano_ crece bastante.